# String formatting for a number

Tags: python

I have the following number:

```
0006.5400
0000.5400
0000.0000
```

How would I get strip all leading zero's on the left, except if the first digit is a zero. Is there a 'limit' on `lstrip()`?

I was able to fix this at the database level, but curious anyways.

Comment: Are the dashes indicating negative numbers?

Comment: (No, I changed it to make it clearer.)

Comment: @David542 What's the output that you need? All leading zeros removed or just a few of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are they always decimal strings?

```
>>> float("0000.0000")
0.0
>>> float("0006.5400")
6.54
>>> float("0000.5400")
0.54
```

EDIT:

As Matt suggested below, you can also use:

`'%0.4f' % float("0000.5400")`

Comment: or `'%.4f' % float("0000.0000")` possibly

Answer (score 1):

This strips the insignificant zeros on the left but preserves the zeros on the right.

```
import decimal
D = decimal.Decimal

for s in ('0006.5400', '0000.5400', '0000.0000'):
    print(D(s))
```

yields

```
6.5400
0.5400
0.0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest solution is just to use `lstrip()` and then add a leading `"0"` if necessary.